# How to add widget that are defined in the kv file in kivy/python?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

i have a table , i want to add rows for it  each time a function  called 
the commun way to do that is to define a widget inside the function and add it each time 
but i don't want to define my widget inside my code i want to define it in my kv file like a template then reference it by the function by using ids or Object 
first is this possible if so  can you tell me how  ?

the way i used to do it is i bind a function to button or text validation event and let us say the function is btn()

```
def btn():
   someLabel = Label(text="some text")
   self.add_widget(someLabel)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually share your code and what have you tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes), you can use `Factory`. For example:

in kivy:

```
<ImageButton@Button>:
    source: None

    Image:
        source: root.source
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.size
```

then in python you can do:

```
from kivy.factory import Factory
button_inst = Factory.ImageButton()
```